# CSS: Inconsistent input tag appearance (Firefox & Safari)

Tags: css, firefox, input

I'm trying to figure out why my input tags looks fairly uneven in Firefox & Safari
Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: http://oi48.tinypic.com/347uwxx.jpg]

I used Firebug & the Safari developer tools to have an idea what's going on.
It seems like Firefox adds another 1 pixel to each border, this results in another 4 pixels
which makes the input look bigger and annoying. Plus the text looks like it's a bit higher in Firefox. is it because of the extra pixels? Or something else?

Anyway, I'd love to get some pointers as to why those pixels are added in Firefox.

```
#signup-form form input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    height:20px;
    padding:2px 4px;
    width:300px;
    color:#a1a1a1;
    font-style:italic;
    display:block;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 0px
}
```

Comment: And where is the code you used that makes all this happen?  Otherwise, you should be aware that input elements' style are as per each browser and OS... in other words, you'll have to put a lot of CSS effort into achieving cross-browser rendering consistency.

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS reset?

Comment: Hi, Yes I'm using a css reset + my answer now includes the input css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `border-width: 2px;`.   Elements are rendered differently across browsers and operating systems, it's just something web developers have to live with.  Form elements are more subject to this than others.